# How to scrape item names from site and while doing so going into a loop entering item links and parsing descriptions also?

Tags: python, scrapy

So I'm total newb to scraping and trying to learn scrapy.

https://www.killertools.com/Dent-Removal-Aluminum-Steel_c_11.html
For starters I want to scrape item names from all products in first category from both pages if more than 1 page of product is there to browse through.

This is what I got and it works:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'killertools'
    start_urls = ['https://www.killertools.com/Dent-Removal-Aluminum-Steel_c_11.html',
              ]

def parse(self, response):

    for item in response.css('div.name'):
        yield {'Name': item.xpath('a/text()').get()}


    next_page = response.css('div.paging a:nth-child(4)::attr("href")').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

But I want to go into each product link and also extract items descriptions and put them into vocabulary as description. How do I go about doing that?

I tried something like this:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'killertools'
    start_urls = ['https://www.killertools.com/Dent-Removal-Aluminum-Steel_c_11.html',
              ]

def parse(self, response):

    for item in response.css('div.name'):
        yield {'Name': item.xpath('a/text()').get()}
        detail_page = response.css('div.name a::attr("href")').get()
        if detail_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(detail_page)
            for detail in response.css('div.item'):
                yield {'Description': detail.xpath('p/strong/text').get()}

    next_page = response.css('div.paging a:nth-child(4)::attr("href")').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

But it does some weird things that I can't really wrap my head around at my level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For starters I want to scrape item names from all products in first category from both pages if more than 1 page of product is there to browse through.

#### Suggestion 0

Try to wrap your head around XPATH!

#### Suggestion 1

On the bottom of the page, close to the pagination links, you'll find a "View All". This adds `?viewall=1` to the original URL. For the URL that you gave, all 21 items are put on one. Seems that you do not need to worry about pagination any longer.

#### Suggestion 2

In order to fetch the product descriptions, a two-step process is conceivable:

1. collect the URLs of the product pages
   `response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "product-item")]/div[@class="name"]/a/@href').getall()`
   should get you pretty close.
   Check the URLs. You might need to prepend the base url. `urllib`is your fiend here.
2. run a second spider to process all these links and read the descriptions from there
   On the product pages, you will find th description in a nicely structured way:
   `response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/ul/li/text()').getall()`
   will get you all lines behind the bullet points.

#### Suggestion 3

Be kind! Don't hammer their site with unnecessary requests. While testing, your custom settings should include `'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True`. Take a look at [HTTPCACHE](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-enabled) for details.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thank You so much, after writing that first part I knew it was complete random shot at doing what I wanted so I was looking exactly for that kind of advice pointing me into proper tools for the job.

Comment: I tried to use what you pointed me to somewhat but I still can't manage to get it working. This is what I came up with and im clueless on how to make start_urls from second spider inherit info from first spider.https://gyazo.com/d78d94aeab8382d223b3f2e42fc49e4e